# changes made inside attached volume in container not coming up in host volume

Tags: docker

when i attach a volume and run a container and make changes inside the container the changes are not reflected inside the attached volume in the host. 
This is the command i am using:

docker run -v datacontainer:/opt/ -i -t ubuntu:16.04

datacontainer is a folder inside the host in the current directory. i am creating a file inside the /opt directory inside the container but when i stop the container and check inside the datacontainer folder in the host it is not present.can someone tell me why is it happening?

Comment: in my case it works: i have a mounted folder with docker-compose and if i create a file inside the container and stop the container the file is still available at my host. i dont know if it makes a diffrent to run your container with -d and execute it with the interactive terminal or like in your case.

Comment: i am not using docker compose but when i try running container in detached mode and try to get the nginx logs from container to host machine it works ::      docker run -d -v /home/ubuntu/datacontainer:/var/log/nginx -p 5005:80 -i -t nginx

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old thread but I think the problem was your syntax.   This would have worked, note the extra dot slash indicating the "datacontainer" folder is in your current directory:

```
docker run -v ./datacontainer:/opt/ -i -t ubuntu:16.04
```

Without that dot slash, you are specifying a volume name (which was created via "docker volume create") instead of a path.

This also explains why @Arghya had success, s/he specified absolute path which differentiated from a volume name.