# Changes to filesystem inside container not reflected on host in docker volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working on an Express server written on TypeScript. The flow of the project is that I have a npm build script in place which takes project files in src folder and compiles them to the dist folder. Both these folders live under the root directory. The project works, but while trying to move everything to docker, although I am mounting the volume and the built files (dist directory) is there in the container, the changes are not reflected on host. (I am using Windows + VirtualBox for Docker)

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460271/changes-made-inside-attached-volume-in-container-not-coming-up-in-host-volume) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192119/directory-created-inside-docker-container-not-reflecting-on-host-machine) questions. I see that their scenario is same, but their solutions don't seem to work for me. I made sure I am using similar techniques mentioned in answers to these, they don't seem to work.

Directory Structure of the Project:

```
├── Backend
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── controllers/
│   │   ├── models/
│   │   ├── routes/
│   │   ├── services/
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   └── server.ts
│   ├── dist/ (Created upon compilation)
│   │   ├── controllers/
│   │   ├── data/ (Created upon starting the server)
│   │   ├── models/
│   │   ├── routes/
│   │   ├── services/
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── server.js
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── tslint.json
│   └── .env
├── Frontend/ (This part is an independent application)
├── docker-compose.yml
└── README.md
```

When the server starts, it creates a directory in `%proj_root%/Backend/dist` named `data` which is used to give input to the application via txt files. Compilation works fine as evident from ls commands I have put in Dockerfile, but the changes done inside of the container (creation of the dist directory) isn't reflected on host. On host, the dist directory is empty, causing the server to crash because there is no server.js file.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./Backend/
    volumes:
      - ./Backend/dist:/app/dist
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./Backend:/app
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./Frontend
    ports:
      - "3001:8080"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./Frontend:/app
```

Here's the Dockerfile for Backend service:

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . . # Copying everything to enable standalone usage
RUN ls # Logging before tsc build
RUN npm run build
RUN ls /app/dist # Logging after tsc build. All the built files are visible.
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Upon running `docker-compose up`, a dist folder should be created in container (`/app/dist`) and should be reflected on host as `%proj_root%/Backend/dist`

I understand I could create a script which compiles TS and then runs docker-compose, but that looks like a hacky approach to me. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Delete all of the `volumes:` except the one that holds the data that needs to be persisted.  They're hiding everything the Dockerfile does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `docker-compose.yml` setup you show does two independent things.  First, it builds a Docker image, using the `Dockerfile` you give it in isolation.  Second, it takes that image, mounts volumes and applies other settings, and runs a container based on those settings.  The Docker image build sequence ignores all of these other settings; nothing you do in the Dockerfile can ever change files on the host system.

When you run a container, whatever content is in the `volumes:` settings you pass in completely **replaces** what came out of that image.  This is always a one-way "push into the container": the contents of your host's `Backend` directory replace `/app` in the container; the contents of an anonymous volume replace its `node_modules`, and the contents of the host's `list` directory replace `/app/dist`.

There is one special-case exception to this.  When you start a container, if the volume mount is empty, the contents from the image get copied to the volume.  This only happens if there's absolutely nothing in the volume tree at all.  If there's already content in the `dist` host directory, or the `node_modules` anonymous volume, this replaces whatever was in the image, even if it changed in the image (or changed in the volume, Docker has no way to tell).

As a one-off workaround, if you

```
rm -rf dist
```

then the next time you launch the container, Docker will notice that the `dist` directory is empty and repopulate it from the image.

I'd recommend just deleting these `volumes:` settings altogether.  If you're actively developing the software, do it on the host: Node is very easy to install with typical OS package managers, your IDE won't be confused by your Node interpreter being hidden inside a container, and you won't hit this sort of problem.  When you go to deploy, you can just use the Docker image as-is, without separately distributing the code that's also inside the image.

Comment: Thanks for your patience to read everything and help. I now understand what happens when. I had put `./Backend:/app` to enable hot-reload of my node project, however, I see that it's technically flawed to make it work that way, I have removed it, thanks for helping at that front. As you have mentioned that if I delete the directory `./Backend/dist`, docker will find that there is no dist directory on mounted volume, but there's one in image, so it creates one on the volume (which is reflected on host). But I see that the dist directory visible on host is empty. Hence the server crashes.

Comment: I believe, as per your original answer, mounting actually overwrites what's there in volume, but if the `dist` directory is created while starting the container, why is it empty and doesn't contain the built js code on host? 

Also, if you could link any documentation around volume mounting lifecycle, it'll be great. `docker-compose`, the official documentation is helpful, but does not mention the lifecycle and behavior of mounted volumes.

Comment: Lastly, I took your advice of deleting everything that's there under volumes section and just mapped the `data` folder to give input to the container and it works flawlessly. However, I still wanna learn why making the mapping `./Backend/dist:/app/dist` after `rm -rf Backend/dist` is resulting in an empty directory inside of the volume. Thanks in advance!